# ratcave : 'scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.Rotation' object has no attribute 'as_dcm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet, ratcave

I'm trying to create a project using ratcave for python. But when I import ratcave, I get the following error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.Rotation' object has no attribute 'as_dcm'
> ```

and this is the full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PROJECT_PATH\src\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ratcave as rc
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import resources
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\resources.py", line 40, in <module>
    default_camera = Camera()
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\camera.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.projection = PerspectiveProjection() if not projection else projection
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\utils\observers.py", line 56, in __setattr__
    super(AutoRegisterObserver, self).__setattr__(key, value)
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\camera.py", line 299, in projection
    self.reset_uniforms()
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\camera.py", line 302, in reset_uniforms
    self.uniforms['projection_matrix'] = self.projection_matrix.view()
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\shader.py", line 139, in uniforms
    self.update()
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\utils\observers.py", line 47, in update
    self.on_change()
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\physical.py", line 186, in on_change
    Physical.on_change(self)
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\physical.py", line 138, in on_change
    self.model_matrix = np.dot(self.position.to_matrix(), self.rotation.to_matrix())
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\coordinates.py", line 126, in to_matrix
    return self.to_radians().to_matrix()
  File "PROJECT_PATH\venv\lib\site-packages\ratcave\coordinates.py", line 95, in to_matrix
    mat[:3, :3] = R.from_euler(self.axes[1:],self._array,degrees=False).as_dcm() # scipy as_matrix() not available
AttributeError: 'scipy.spatial.transform._rotation.Rotation' object has no attribute 'as_dcm'. Did you mean: '_uniforms'?
```

This is my code:

```
import pyglet
import ratcave as rc


# Create Window
window = pyglet.window.Window()


pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the error messages. Past the error messages in the question.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the method name has changed to `from_matrix`.

---

In `scipy.spatial.Rotation` methods `from_dcm`, `as_dcm` were renamed to `from_matrix`, `as_matrix` respectively.

reference:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/5f4c4d802e5a56708d86909af6e5685cd95e6e66/doc/release/1.4.0-notes.rst

---

I hope that problem is resolved.